# Get XML node list using property value

Tags: c#, xml

I'd like to get the nodes in a list who has the property `isRequired = true`. from following xml , I should get accountno and city in my node list. I am using `XmlDocument`. Can someone suggest how to do it?

```
<sqltables>

     <account>
      <accountno Type="int" Exec="GetGlobalValue" isRequired="true"/>
      <accountname Type="string" Exec="GetGlobalValue" />
    </account>

    <address>
      <city Type="string" Exec="GetGlobalValue" isRequired="true"/>
      <stateType="string" Exec="GetGlobalValue" />
      <zipcode Type="string" Exec="GetGlobalValue" />
   </address>
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried already.  Do you have a requirement to use `XmlDocument`?  `XDocument`, which enables Linq-to-XML is far easier to use.

Comment: I am not using Linq to XML . I am using XMLdocument which will load xml data like below   XmlDocument ExampleDataXml = new XmlDocument();
                        ExampleDataXml.LoadXml(XmlData);                                                I need to find out the XML nodes who has isRequired to true in this xmldocument.

Comment: I'm aware of that.  However, you haven't posted any code, or explained *why* you are using `XmlDocument` instead of  `XDocument` for this simple use-case.  If you are going to add code, please edit your question and show us what you've already attempted.

Comment: I have not coded yet. I am a beginner . I want to know how can I find the nodes using xmldocument. I have not used Xdocument because it is old existing application , there is no room to change it now.

Comment: you can suggest me how to do it using Xdocument. I'd use Xdocument instead of xmldocument

Comment: Provided both possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is far easier in using Linq-to-XML, but using the `XmlDocument` you can locate nodes by using XPath queries.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlData);
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//account/accountno[@isRequired='true']");
```

You can then iterate on `nodes` to access the data.  You would just write a simlar XPath expression for the account-city type query.  Personally, I'm not an XPath expert so take the above expression with a grain of salt.  Here's the MSDN on locating elements via XPath: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx(v=vs.110).aspx

This is far easier in `XDocument` (aka Linq-to-XML)

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlData);
var nodes = doc.Descendants("accountno").Where(n => n.Attribute("isRequired").Value.equals("true"));
```

*NOTE: The above lambda can cause a* `NullReferenceException` *if you aren't careful*

You can then iterate on `nodes` in this as well, however this time it returns a `IEnumerable<XElement>` object instead of a `XmlNodeList`.  Here's a good starting point for Linq-to-XML:   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

**EDIT:**

Per the comments below here is an example linq query that returns everything where "isRequired.equals("true)" is true regardless of the tag's element name:

```
doc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Attribute("isRequired") != null && n.Attribute("isRequired").Value.Equals("true"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I don't want to specify the decendant node . It should loop through whole xml and find the nodes for me with isRequired value to true. I tried followingXDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlData);
                        var nodelist = xDoc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Attribute("isRequired").Value.Equals("true")); but it is giving me object reference not set to an object error.

Comment: Haha I warned you that would happen!  That's because you can't call the `Value` property on `null`.  You need to do a check for null prior to calling variable.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I tried following code var nodelist = xDoc.Descendants().Where(n => n.Attribute("isRequired") != null).Select( a => a.Attribute("isRequired").Value.Equals("true")); but I am getting result in nodes as [0] = true . how can i get the node name?

Comment: Select is used for projections, which you don't want to do.  See my edit.  Also please look at the API documentation that I linked to you.

Comment: If this answered your original question, please upvote & mark accepted to close out the question.  Thanks.